# how to convert from hyperspectral(.hyspex format) to tiff(geoTiff)

Tags: java, tiff

I have a `hyperspectral` or `Multispectal` image. I want to convert from `hyspex` to `tiff`. It can be in `Matlab` or `Java` or other programming language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very broad. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hyspex file this is a raw file before any radiometric calibration. You should first run HySpex RAD to calibrate the file , then you can use various software to convert it tiff, probably ENVI is the easiest.  You can of course also convert the hyspex file also directly to tiff without doing the calibration first.